# Display a timer that loops every 15 seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

I made this code, but there is a delay between the time loop showing on the screen and the exact elapsed time.

```
Timer t = new Timer();
int time = 15;
string timestr;
t.Interval = 1000;
t.Tick += new EventHandler(Time);
```

---

```
void Time(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (time == 0)
    { time = 15; }
    if (time != 0)
    {
        time--;
        timestr = time.ToString();
        label.Text = timestr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to do a `label.Refresh()` after setting the 'Text' property to get an immediate update? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx

Comment: @hatchet No, you don't.

Comment: How far out is it? I'm not sure that a `Timer` is the most accurate timer you can use, for a start. How accurate do you need it to be?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem. Is it that you're trying to get it to sync up with wall time? If so, how close do you need it to be and how close is it now?

Comment: Does adding label.Update(); in your timer help. Without this the label will only be updated on screen when your program is idle.

Comment: the timer stops when i call a function with my mouse click and then continues..

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are off by one second since the timer won't fire its first event until that interval value is reached.

A quick fix would be to fire the event yourself when you start it:

```
t.Start();
Time(t, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: where should i put this code? I put it in the timer event and it gives me infinite loop.

Comment: @ВладимирРадески Where ever you are starting your timer. It's not clear from your post where you are doing that.  If at the start of the program, I would override the OnShown method of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try this. Add the line Application.DoEvents() just before the end of Time function.

```
void Time(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (time == 0)
   { time = 15; }
   if (time != 0)
   {
       time--;
       timestr = time.ToString();
       label.Text = timestr;
   }
   Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Comment: I would not suggest doing this, `Application.DoEvents()` should be used very sparingly. How do you expect it to help here?